# How to vertically align (justify) multiple elements

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, vertical-text

I am not quite sure how to say what I want but I am going to try. I want to vertically align three different elements, all three wrapped in individual divs. Currently this is my code:

```css
.service_info {
  margin-top: 45px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "source-sans-pro", sans-serif;
}
.title_text_serviceinfo {
  margin-top: 85px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #333132;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "source-sans-pro", sans-serif;
}
.service_info_times {
  margin-top: -110px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 175%;
  border-left: 5px solid #0b496f;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #333132;
}
.service_info_events {
  postion: fixed;
  left: 300px;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 175%;
  color: #333132;
}
```

```html
<!--Service Information-->

<section class="service_info">
  <h2 class="secondary_header"> When We Gather </h2>

  <h3 class="title_text_serviceinfo"> Sunday </h3> 
  <div class="service_info_times">
    <ul>
      <li>7:00am</li>
      <li>8:30am</li>
      <li>9:00am</li>
      <li>10:15am</li>
      <li>4:00pm</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="service_info_events">
    <ul>
      <li>Men's Prayer</li>
      <li>Fellowship Time</li>
      <li>Sunday School</li>
      <li>Worship Service</li>
      <li>Revolution Student Ministries</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h3 class="title_text_serviceinfo"> Monday </h3>
  <div class="service_info_times">
    <ul>
      <li>6:00pm</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="service_info_events">
    <ul>
      <li>Precept Bible Study</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h3 class="title_text_serviceinfo"> Tuesday </h3>
  <div class="service_info_times">
    <ul>
      <li>9:15am</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="service_info_events">
    <ul>
      <li>P.E.A.R.L.S. (Lady's Ministry</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h3 class="title_text_serviceinfo"> Wednesday </h3>
  <div class="service_info_times">
    <ul>
      <li>7:00am</li>
      <li>7:00pm</li>
      <li>7:00pm</li>
      <li>7:00pm</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="service_info_events">
    <ul>
      <li>Stronger Senior</li>
      <li>CLC</li>
      <li>Club 56</li>
      <li>House of Prayer</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Feel free to help me correct any other errors...I just started learning how to code a website.

Here is an image of what I want the final product to be: (I have to link to it since I am new to this site.)

[fujifame.com/art260/](http://fujifame.com/art260/)

Comment: you may rethink the structure and use display:flex/table or inline-block http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/raovxv drop the idea of negative margin and position :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** @GCyrillus Has a codepen that's even cleaner: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/raovxv

I managed to somewhat hack your code into submission. I hope this helps you out but your code really needs to be rewritten. Based on the image you have, you should have 2 columns of divs. The day of the week should be in the first column div and the events should be in the second. Add the css property `foat:left;` to your second column divs, and clear them using the CSS property `clear:` if they arent moving down to the next column. Hope this gives you a head start! Here you go.

```css
.header{ clear:both; }
.service_info {
  margin-top: 45px;

  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "source-sans-pro", sans-serif;
}
.title_text_serviceinfo {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
  color: #333132;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "source-sans-pro", sans-serif;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  width:140px;
}
.service_info_times {
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*margin-left: 200px;*/
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 175%;
  border-left: 5px solid #0b496f;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #333132;
  float:left;
  clear:right;
}
.service_info_events {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 175%;
  color: #333132;
  clear:right;
}

.secondMargin{ margin-top:40px; }
.thirdMargin{ margin-top:80px; }
```

```html
<section class="service_info">
  <div id = "header">
    <h2 class="secondary_header"> When We Gather </h2>
  </div>

  <h3 class="title_text_serviceinfo"> Sunday </h3> 
  <div class="service_info_times">
    <ul>
      <li>7:00am Men's Prayer</li>
      <li>8:30am Fellowship Time</li>
      <li>9:00am Sunday School</li>
      <li>10:15am Worship Service</li>
      <li>4:00pm Revolution Student Ministries</li>
    </ul>
  </div>



  <h3 class="title_text_serviceinfo secondMargin"> Monday </h3>
  <div class="service_info_times">
    <ul>
      <li>6:00pm Precept Bible Study</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h3 class="title_text_serviceinfo secondMargin"> Tuesday </h3>
  <div class="service_info_times">
    <ul>
      <li>9:15am P.E.A.R.L.S. (Lady's Ministry)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h3 class="title_text_serviceinfo"> Wednesday </h3>
  <div class="service_info_times">
    <ul>
      <li>7:00am Stronger Senior</li>
      <li>7:00pm CLC</li>
      <li>7:00pm Club 56</li>
      <li>7:00pm House of Prayer</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```