# How to Vertically Center Multiple Elements?

Tags: html, css, centering

I've looked all across this site (and the rest of the internet), and the only question which actually mentions vertically centering two or more is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177759/how-to-vertically-align-justify-multiple-elements), but the only answer there seems to just be an entire code review. In the process of learning CSS, I still cannot reliably position things centrally in the order I want them. Horizontally centering is often just as difficult, although I've managed in the minimal code example below. I know of [howtocenterincss.com](http://howtocenterincss.com/) but that only lets me align one thing vertically.

In the following code example, I want the two buttons collectively to be centered in the div, arranged one above the other, with a margin in between them. I've managed to get half way there, but can't quite figure out how to align them vertically within the div.

```css
#buttonContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 3px black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button id="b1" class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button id="b2" class="button">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not a good idea to apply absolute positioning where you don't want overlapping. You can use flexbox to achieve desired layout. Demo:

```css
#buttonContainer {
  /* make element inline flex-container */
  /* this will make its children flex-items */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* align-items items in column */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* center items horizontally */
  align-items: center;
  /* center items vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  
  border: solid 3px black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button id="b1" class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button id="b2" class="button">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
#buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 3px black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button id="b1" class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button id="b2" class="button">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`inline-flex` support in IE10+

`flex-direction` support in IE11 only

`align-items` support in IE11 only

**So, i Prefer dont use this properties,i use this way :**

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
#buttonContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 3px black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.button {
    display: block;
    margin:2px;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
    <div class="center">
        <button id="b1" class="button">Button 1</button>
        <button id="b2" class="button">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```